# Python When match two columns then

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the equivalent of this code

```
df_train['uf'] = (df_train['home_score'] + df_train['away_score'] < 4) * 1
```

for

```
df_train['d'] = (df_train['home_score'] = df_train['away_score']) * 1
```

When `True` = `1` when `False` = `0`

Comment: chain `astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison operator is `==` not `=`:

```
df_train['d'] = (df_train['home_score'] == df_train['away_score']).astype(int)
```

or:

```
df_train['d'] = df_train['home_score'].eq(df_train['away_score']).astype(int)
```

or:

```
df.eval('home_score == away_score').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly...
I think you got mistake on match condition on second code block.
Please try this one.

```
df_train['d'] = (df_train['home_score'] == df_train['away_score']).astype(int)
```

If it doesn't sth what you expect, please share more details. Thanks

Comment: This is already [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711033/16343464) ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. During the write my answer, I didn't refresh the browser so I didn't know you had already same answer. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries, it happened to me as well

Comment: as it was a good answer I +1'd you on another (good) answer